# How to convert objects inside the array - JSON to Dart List with serialized model?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  var result = await httpCalls(....);

  List<UserModel> users = [];

  await result['users'].map((e) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> a = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(e));
    users.add(UserModel.fromJson(a));
  }).toList();
```

I am receiving an array of `UserModel` from the http calls. Currently, I am converting one by one to add it to the `List<UserModel> users`.

Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you've added the `async` keyword in your lambda, nor why you encode and then decode each element.

The important trick with `List.map<T>()` is to give it a generic type. This way it returns an iterable of the correct type and, in turn, the `toList` will give you  the correct type.

```
  final list = (results['users'] as List<dynamic>)
      .map<UserModel>((elem) => UserModel.fromJson(elem))
      .toList();
```

This takes the `List<dynamic>` you get from the decoded JSON (you can probably omit the `as` that I added for emphasis) and calls `map`. By typing the map, the compiler knows that the lambda must return a `UserModel` - so it will end up with an iterable of only user models, which can then be turned into a list of them. Thus the compiler knows that `list` is a `List<UserModel>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode("response here");
  List<UserModel> users = List<UserModel>.from(parsedJson.map<UserModel>((dynamic i) => UserModel.fromJson(i)));
```

This will generate a list from the result of all UserModels